# For Loop redudancies, repeating data from 1 page

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I tried to get the every data from website in every page, so i made a loop inside a loop. for example, i made a loop for 4 pages, and get every 2 top data. but instead of getting 2 data each page, i got a redudancies in the first page.

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = 'http://example.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Files\\chromedriver_79_win.exe")
driver.get(url)

list_kode=[]

for i in range(4): # 4 pages 
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser") 
    for j in range(2): # 2 top item
        list_kode.append(soup.findAll("td", class_="sorting_1")[j].text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-dt-idx="9"]').click()
    # click to next page

list_kode
```

Output

```
['13784044',
 '13783044',
 '13784044',
 '13783044',
 '13572044',
 '13571044',
 '13355044',
 '13354044']
```

If you see the 1st & 2nd data was the same with the 3rd & 4th data, and I dont get to the 4th page data.

[image]

Comment: check this `soup.findAll("td", class_="sorting_1")[j].text` if you are getting two values

Comment: post the part of the code prior to list_kode=[]. Hard to debug without seeing the full thing

Comment: @chitown88 I've edited the code, but nothing fancy, list_kode=[] is an empty object.

Comment: @louislugas I understand that. I want to see the selenium code you used to generate that (including the urls). What's the url?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the script runs too fast. It's not waiting for the next page doesn't render fast enough. So you need to put some time delay in there. The prefered way is to use seleniums implicit wait and not `time.sleep()`, but I didn't have time to look into that.

Secondly, you may just be able to pull the data without selenium (see/try the second script below):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


url = 'http://lpse.polri.go.id/eproc4/lelang'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

list_kode=[]

for i in range(4): # 4 pages 
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser") 
    for j in range(2): # 2 top item
        list_kode.append(soup.findAll("td", class_="sorting_1")[j].text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-dt-idx="9"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    # click to next page

driver.close()
print (list_kode)
```

**Without Selenium:**

```
import requests

url = 'http://lpse.polri.go.id/eproc4/lelang'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

s = requests.session()
response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
cookie = s.cookies.get_dict()
cookieKey = list(cookie.keys())[0]
cookieVal = cookie[list(cookie.keys())[0]]
authToken = cookieVal.split('AT=')[-1].split('&')[0]
ts = cookieVal.split('TS=')[-1].split('&')[0]

url = 'http://lpse.polri.go.id/eproc4/dt/lelang'
 #'Cookie': list(cookie.keys())[0] + '=' + cookie[list(cookie.keys())[0]]}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Cookie': cookieKey + '=' + cookieVal}

list_kode=[]

for i in range(4): # 4 pages 

    payload = {
    'draw': i,
    'columns[0][data]': '0',
    'columns[0][name]': '',
    'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[0][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[0][search][value]': '',
    'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
    'columns[1][data]': '1',
    'columns[1][name]': '',
    'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[1][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[1][search][value]': '',
    'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
    'columns[2][data]': '2',
    'columns[2][name]': '',
    'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[2][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[2][search][value]': '',
    'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
    'columns[3][data]': '3',
    'columns[3][name]': '',
    'columns[3][searchable]': 'false',
    'columns[3][orderable]': 'false',
    'columns[3][search][value]': '',
    'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
    'columns[4][data]': '4',
    'columns[4][name]': '',
    'columns[4][searchable]': 'true',
    'columns[4][orderable]': 'true',
    'columns[4][search][value]': '',
    'columns[4][search][regex]': 'false',
    'order[0][column]': '0',
    'order[0][dir]': 'desc',
    'start': i*25,
    'length': '25',
    'search[value]': '',
    'search[regex]': 'false',
    'authenticityToken': authToken,
    '_': ts}


    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    for j in range(2): # 2 top item
        list_kode.append(jsonData['data'][j][0])

print (list_kode)
```

Comment: doesn't work. it goes [page 1, page 2, page 2, page 2]. i think i'll do it manually for a while due to deadline. thanks.

Comment: You can’t share the url?

Comment: My only guess is you’ll have to identify the next page button by another way other than xpath. That could be causing the issue. But again, I can’t debug if I don’t have the url.

Comment: this is the url [link](http://lpse.polri.go.id/eproc4/lelang), my personal guess is the loading time from the website is too long, sometimes it got some error (cannot find the xpath element), so i think i have to break the for loops manually

Comment: Where’s the link. You could use sleniums wait function. It will wait to execute the next bit until the xpath shows up

Comment: @louislugas I think the issue is the script runs too fast. It doesn't render fast enough. So you need to put some time delay in there. The preferred way is to use seleniums implicit wait and not `time.sleep()`. secondly, you might be able to skip selenium and go straight to the source (check the second solution)